# Here Maps Marker

Tags: javascript, c#, here-api

I am using multible marker for tracking object in the map, and I want to change the position of the marker without erasing all the markers. IMEI is my ID to control the relation between non changed and changed markers. Please help me about that.

Sent data: IMEI:123456
Lat:xxxx
Lon:yyy

current Marker: IMEI:123456
Lat:xxxx+1
Lon:yyy+1

if (Array.R2 == markerList[i].IMEI)
markerList[i].setPosition(latlng);

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.
read this question to learn about format your question.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Sorry this question cannot be understood. Can you please post some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

For your case you need to use a hash map with a IMEI key:

```
  var markers = {};//define a marker's hash map.

  markers[IMEI_value1] = new H.map.Marker({lat:xxxx1, lng:yyyy1});
  map.addObject(markers[IMEI_value1]);

  markers[IMEI_value2] = new H.map.Marker({lat:xxxx2, lng:yyyy2});
  map.addObject(markers[IMEI_value2]);
  //etc.... for all markers
  //later when some IMEI will be changed a geo-position:
  markers[IMEI_value1].setPosition({lat:xxxx_new, lng:yyyy_new});
```